# What's the name of the bar below the Property grid in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor extension to help darken up VS2010, found a nice theme that I like however I've got one big problem with it.

On the Property sheet, at the bottom where it says the name of the property and a sort description this theme I'm using is impossible to read; Black on a dark grey background. Unfortunately, I don't know what this specific segment of the Property window is called to change it.

[image]

Comment: do you want to change the text color, or the background color ?

Comment: @Samuel_xL Either would be acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the text color with the extension.

To figure that out, copy `FFFFFF`, select all line in the theme editor configuration pane (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (yes, you can do that, pretty neat !) and hit apply : everything that can be themed will then appear white. The text however, will stay black.

You can hopefully change the background color : It's called **ToolWindowBackground**. It will affect all tool windows of course. There's no specific item for this window in particular.